# Force Apache2 web server to listen on a single external IP

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy

I'm trying to force Apache2 web server to listen on a single external IP which belongs to a HAProxy (`192.168.50.30`) so the users have to go through HAProxy to consume Apache2 web server. At the moment (unfortunately) users can access Apache2 web server via `http://192.168.50.10` and `http://192.168.50.30` (only this should be allowed).

- HAProxy IP: `192.168.50.30`
- Apache2 IP: `192.168.50.10`

The mosts posts say that changing `Listen *:80` to `Listen IP-ADDRESS:80` in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` does the trick but I get error below when I try to restart apache2.

```
(99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 192.168.50.30:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

**MY CURRENT SETTINGS**

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
Listen 192.168.50.30:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       webserver1      webserver1
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

**$ ifconfig -a**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b5:33:dd  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb5:33dd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:63695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:75453727 (75.4 MB)  TX bytes:983784 (983.7 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9a:05:45  
          inet addr:192.168.50.10  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe9a:545/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8392 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:656568 (656.5 KB)  TX bytes:872702 (872.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [access control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) for this. First ensure that your Listen statements all list only 1 IP address (but that may not really matter). Then configure an access control to only allow access from the HA Proxy address

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.50.30
```

or something similar will only allow access from the haproxy address.

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from 192.168.50.30
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind to IP's that show up in ifconfig (ie local IPs).  It sounds instead like you want to limit Apache to only respond when HAProxy connects to it.

You can do this with IPTables on the Apache host:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.30 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

This says to allow connections to port 80 from 192.168.1.30, and to reject all other connections.

Do 'iptables -L' beforehand to see if any other rules are in place, that may change the specifics of how you add these.

Another option is to use Apache access control to do the same thing: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require ip 192.168.1.30
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: I did what you did but web server is not accessible from anywhere at all now. Please see the output here: http://pastebin.com/T1MF0Fyk

Comment: This is the current output: http://pastebin.com/fdQ7GHkp

Comment: So if you log in to 192.168.1.30 and try to curl the webserver, it doesn't work?

Comment: No it doesn't. Anyway thanks for the answer. +1 for iptables.

Answer (score -1):

You can just change "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf" config files as below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> to <VirtualHost 192.168.50.30:80>
```

It will resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried that before so it won't work and I'm not after vhost solution anyway. What would work in vhost is to set `Allow from 192.168.50.30` in `<Directory ...>` block.